# DDoS might be very unlikely to happen to my website but in any case a CDN that should protect from it slows my website

Tags: attack-prevention, ddos, shared-hosting, cdn

I humbly assume that DDoS is very unlikely to happen to my website.

A CDN that should protect from it slows my website according to my personal experience and tests (perhaps only because of the strange demand to have all webpages redirected to `www.` versions when the CDN is active, perhaps not only because of that) and it's also in beta version (supplied by my hosting provider itself) so I might just want to disable it.

Given that my hosting is **shared hosting**, would the very fact that the hosting is "shared" and the hoster must protect the environment shared **by me and other customers** actually redeems me from the need of a CDN to protect from DDoS attacks?

Comment: Your question is basically *"I know DDoS protection is a good thing, but do I really need it?"*. How are we supposed to answer that for you? We don't know how much financial damage your site will suffer if it is attacked vs how much financial damage it will suffer by keeping the DDoS protection in place. Only you can make that decision.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I don't intend to ask the question you have presented; I didn't even think about financial damage at any point (rather, on how to bring back the latest working version of the website if a DDoS attack took place), the only question I ask is if the very renting of shared hosting redeems me from the need of a CDN to protect from a somewhat likely DDoS attack, or not (?).

Comment: I see. Does the shared hosting provider include DDoS filtering as part of their service offering?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I don't know; it's a huge company (Namecheap) so I guess that at least **informally** they would, but that's just a wild guess...

Comment: What's in your contract? Did you pay for DDoS protection? Do they list it in their marketing page as an included feature?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I paid for a CDN that should suffice such protection ; I don't recall any other mention of DDoS protection (that's true for this company and for any other shared hosting provider I ever worked with).

Comment: Right, so you ask: *"I ask is if the very renting of shared hosting redeems me from the need of a CDN to protect from a somewhat likely DDoS attack, or not*". Some shared hosting providers may pay for loadbalancers with high-quality DDoS services built-in; some may use cheap or ineffective DDoS protection, or some may use no DDoS protection. You're going to have to ask your hosting provider.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth thanks ; sadly I believe that with generally any hosting provider, many doubtfully-outsourced customer support representatives might not even know the answer and might give a long demagogue reply as an "answer" such as "our CDN will protect your website" usual sort of reference without getting into the serious technical detailing... So I think I'll just take the gamble... I thank you and Benny, a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear about your last paragraph so I'll answer a bit broadly.  If you're enabling DDoS protection on a shared hosting system, doing so will protect your site and potentially the other hosted sites from DDoS.  If the other sites are not DDoS protected, an attack directed at them could potentially take your site down, even if your own site is DDoS protected.

Comment: Benny that's a very interesting answer, thanks ; I do wonder if in any of the cases **the hoster** would do anything logical to protect the websites of us all.

Comment: recursiveWithStyle, generally speaking they would have some kind of protection in order to protect their business, but you'd want to ask.  If they aren't a very small company, they almost certainly will have multiple servers with load balancing, which would handle some level of DDoS.